# Can not connect to ms sql server using windows authentication on remote system

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I was trying to connect to ms sql server 2008 which is installed on a remote system.But it showing error.The following is the way i had tried

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.Statement;  


public class mssql {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {  
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();

            Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.220:1433;databaseName=sales;integratedSecurity=true;");
            if(!(connection==null))
            {
                System.out.println("connected");
            }

//            


        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

This is the error i am getting

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.1.220, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at mssql.main(mssql.java:14)
```

Any solutions for this problem

Comment: Can you access the remote server via SQL Server Management Studio or "telnet 192.168.1.220 1433"?

Comment: @Rainer.R It say can not open connection

Comment: @Rainer.R my windows firewall was blocking it,now i am able to telnet. But i can not connect to sql server

Comment: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and **accepting TCP/IP connections at the port**. Make sure that TCP connections to the port **are not blocked by a firewall**."

Answer (score 1):

Is the 2008 SQL instance configured to be `listening` for `TCP` connections?

Start, Microsoft SQL Server 2008, Configuration Tools, SQL Server Configuration Manager
SQL Server Network Configuration
Protocols for [*instance name*]
There should be four items listed:

- Shared Memory
- Named Pipes
- TCP/IP
- VIA

For your environment, which should be enabled and which should be disabled? Most setups call for Shared Memory and TCP/IP enabled, the others disabled.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class mssql {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {  
            //Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance(); modify
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();

            Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.220:1433;databaseName=sales;integratedSecurity=true;");
            if(!(connection==null))
            {
                System.out.println("connected");
            }

//            


        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Then you look at this post：

[JDBC: Simple MSSql connection example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523865/jdbc-simple-mssql-connection-example-not-working)

Comment: It shows this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

Comment: Then you look at this post：http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523865/jdbc-simple-mssql-connection-example-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect from the command line:

```
sqlcmd -S 192.168.1.220 -E
```

Also, check this:

- Is the server firewall configured (allow port 1433 or sqlservr.exe);
- Is your instance name correct? If you are using SQL Server express, the server name would be 192.168.1.220\sqlexpress;
- Are TCP connections enabled for the server (see answer from jdev);
- Are remote connections enabled for the server (can be changed in SQL Server Management Studio, Server properties, Connections);
- Is port 1433 correct? By default, only unnamed instances use static port 1433. Other instances use a dynamic port and require SQL Server Browser for discovery.

Answer (score 0):

-first enable your sql server to receive tcp connection from configuration manager.
-add sqljdbc library to project.
- add the .dll file of the library as vm argument ex: -Djava.library.path=......
-use the code below as example:

```
 String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;" +
     "databaseName=Timesheet;integratedSecurity=true;";
    Connection con = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try {

     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);


     String SQL = "select top 100 * from paycal";
     stmt = con.createStatement();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
     int i =0;

     while (rs.next()) {

        jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString("dayname"), i, 0);
        jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString("dater"), i, 1);
        i++;

     }
```